# gameExit not defined Error

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to understand how to define exiting in pygame. I am making a car game where you have to avoid obstacles from coming into contact with the car.

My error is

```
line 71, in <module>
    while not gameExit:
NameError: name 'gameExit' is not defined
```

My code is

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255,0,0)

car_width = 73

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

pygame.display.set_caption("Hi There Fucker")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load("mycar.png")

def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: " + str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0,0))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    game_loop()

def crash():
    message_display("You crashed")

def game_loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.1)
    y = (display_height * 0.3)

    x_change = 0

    thing_starx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 7
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100

    gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

Comment: Just indent the while loop. It should most likely be inside of the `game_loop` function (hence the name game_**loop**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   thing_height = 100
   # this doesn't define it at a global scope. 
   gameExit = False
## gameExit is not defined
while not gameExit:
```

The problem is that you don't have that value `gameExit` defined yet. Consider defining it earlier at a global scope.

```
pygame.init()

gameExit=False
display_width = 800
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue. Your variable `gameExit` is only defined inside the functions that use it.

The easiest way to fix this would be to declare it to `False` at the start of the program and put `global gameExit` at the top of all of your functions that set it, thus making sure they access the global version of it and don't just re-define it.

For you're purposes, I'm sure this is fine, but you might want to check out the [top answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil).

Comment: Having a global at the start of the function is redundant unless he changes the value of that variable.

Comment: @yakobyd Which he does... look through his code. Specifically, his `game_loop` function

Comment: I have not sayed it is redundant in that scenario I am just correcting his statement "put global gameExit at the top of all of your functions that use it".

Comment: @yakobyd You're right. "Changed it" would be better. Edited